# Siberian unicorns lived until at least 39,000 years ago

Tags: phrase-usage

[BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-46358789):

> The rhino, Elasmotherium sibericum, was thought to have become extinct between 200,000 and 100,000 years ago.
>   By radiocarbon-dating a total of 23 specimens, researchers found the Ice Age giant in fact survived in Eastern Europe and Central Asia until at least 39,000 years ago.

From the context they mean "as recently as 39,000 years ago", i.e. the unicorns became extinct more recently than 39,000 years ago (since some were dated at 39,000 years).

Usually "at least 39,000 years ago" means 39,000 years ago or earlier.

Is the BBC's usage correct?

Comment: It’s “survived until at least <some point it time>”  I assume you’d have no problem with  “survived until at least the 1300s” for example.

Comment: To me it's the same as saying that they "survived until at least 37000 BCE" If they are later found to have survived another ten thousand years you would then say "They are now thought to have survived until after least 27000 BCE". The fact that you are dealing in negative numbers does not alter the direction of the flow of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is idiomatic, so you can't actually get there with logic, at least not unabiguously, but this is how *until at least* and *at least until* is understood in reference to the past. *Until* establishes the frame of reference of marching forward in time, and this carries over to the idea of *at least* as a floor operator. So take *until 39,000 years ago* and regard this as the floor value of being not yet extinct.

There are better and more formal ways of going about this. Instead of using "39,000 years ago", they could have used "39,000 BP". BP means Before Present, and is referenced to the year 1950 by convention. Phrases like *years ago* default to measuring remoteness by starting at the present and ending in the past, whereas ordinary dating schemes are indifferent or favor a viewpoint of time marching forward. So using "BP" in lieu of "years ago" helps avoid having to switch from a present-centered viewpoint to a chronological one.

> By radiocarbon-dating a total of 23 specimens, researchers found the Ice Age giant in fact survived in Eastern Europe and Central Asia until at least 39,000 [BP].

Another minor quibble. Between *until at least* and *at least until*, I prefer the latter in this example. Often, it doesn't seem to matter, but sometimes you want to get the operators in a particular order, and this is one of those times.  You are taking "until 39000 years ago" as a whole and telling us this is a floor value. The emphasis should be on what is new, and that is the revision of the floor value. All of the examples of "until at least" that I could find that passed editors' desks used it for future times. By contrast "at least until" is used about equally for past and future.

Comment: Is the a formal term for "present-centered viewpoint"?